# setTimeOut Inconsistency - Node,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I've set a function to execute in my backend after a certain amount of time, using a setTimeOut. Oddly, if I set the timeout to be less than 60000 ms, the code executes. Anything greater than or equal to that, then the code within the `setTimeout` does not run. After searching online, I think it may have something to do with "The This Problem" as shown in this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem

Based on that article, I was under the impression that I need to use `.bind`, but I am really not too familiar with this and am struggling to get the proper syntax.

My question is, should I be using `.bind()` to fix this issue and if so what is the proper way to add it to the code?

As a current example here is what a version of my code looks like. With this code, the `setTimeout` with 6000 ms works, but the one with 60,000 does not. Happy to provide more information.

// In Front End

```
userComplete(a, b);
```

// In Backend

```
export function userComplete (a,b) {

setTimeout(() => {
    addData(a.proj_sub_id, b, a.proj_instance_id); 
}, 60000);

setTimeout(() => {  
    addData(a.proj_sub_id, b, a.proj_instance_id);
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Please provide more detail on what you mean by "sometimes this works perfectly and other times it does not".  Does it not run?  Does it run late/early?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please provide details.

Comment: Sometimes the function doSomething(); executes exactly after 60 seconds, as intended. Other times, it does not execute at all. It's never a case that it executes early or late. It either does, or does not and as far as I can tell all the factors are the same each time I run it

Comment: How are you calling it and where?

Comment: I tried adding some additional detail, please let me know if it still does not make sense. Rattling my brain a bit on this one.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. Are you trying to run a backend function from your frontend?

Comment: My guess is that your frontend call end with timeout. So you don't see the backend response

Answer (score -1):

You can try passing the function to setTimeout directly and in the function userComplete just call your addData method and try if it works.

```
setTimeout(userComplete,60000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `setInterval` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are two different things, don't mix them up.

Comment: I understand they are different, the reason I recommended `setInterval` is because I believe that this is what David is trying to do.

Comment: Apologize for not making it clear. However, in this case I do not believe I am trying to setInterval as I only want this to execute once, just at a later time. I've tried to revise my question to make it more clear.